# Different results with Boolean and boolean in java

Tags: java, boolean

My code did not give the correct result and I begin to troubleshoot and discovered a strange error, can someone explain this to me.

If I pick up the fields and doing this it becomes result1 == false and result2 == true, why?

```
        MyClass m1 = new MyClass();
        MyClass m2 = new MyClass();

        Field[] fieldsFirst = m1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        Field[] fieldsSecond =  m2.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (int i = 0; i < fieldsFirst.length; i++) {

            Field first = fieldsFirst[i];
            Field second = fieldsSecond[i];

            first.setAccessible(true);
            second.setAccessible(true);

            if(first.get(m1) instanceof Boolean)
            {
               boolean b1 = (Boolean)first.get(m1); 
               boolean b2 = (Boolean)second.get(m2);

               //Here are the results
               boolean result1 = b1 != b2; // false
               boolean result2 = (Boolean)first.get(m1) != (Boolean)second.get(m2); // true

            }
```

If I have:

```
public class MyClass {

private boolean myBoolean = true;

public boolean getMyBoolean()
{
return myBoolean;
}
public void setMyBoolean(booelan inBool)
{
myBoolean = inBool;
}

}
```

Comment: `Boolean` objects need to be compared with `equals`

Comment: Yes, as long as you're comparing **different** references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
boolean result1 = b1 != b2; // false
```

you are comparing primitive values, as `b1` and `b2` result from [unboxing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) from `Boolean` to `boolean`.

In

```
boolean result2 = (Boolean)first.get(m1) != (Boolean)second.get(m2); // true
```

you are comparing references. The result of each `get()` is referencing a different object. As such, the `!=` comparison is `true`.

Comment: @JohanNordli Note that although `equals` might be a solution is some cases, here it would be better to unbox to a primitive.

Comment: so boolean result1 = b1 != b2;  is a better way?

Comment: @JohanNordli In my opinion, yes. Unless you actually want three different values of `Boolean`, ie. `true`, `false`, and `null`. Note also that the unboxing conversion will fail if your reference is `null`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Just like Josh Bloch suggests in Effective Java. *Comparing Wrappers? Unbox the suckers*

Answer (score 2):

`Boolean` is a wrapper around the primitive `boolean`.

> a wrapper class wraps (encloses) around a data type and gives it an
>   object appearance. Wherever, the data type is required as an object,
>   this object can be used. Wrapper classes include methods to unwrap the
>   object and give back the data type.

Source: http://way2java.com/java-lang/wrapper-classes/

Just like with other objects, if you need to compare their values, you need to use `.equals()` and not the comparison operators.

Here:

```
boolean b1 = (Boolean)first.get(m1); 
boolean b2 = (Boolean)second.get(m2);
```

You are converting the `Boolean` to `boolean`. This is called as `unboxing conversion` which is a part of the `AutoBoxing Conversions`. These are called `Auto` because Java automatically does that conversion for you; even if you get rid of the cast.
Hence, you are comparing their primitive values.
Since the primitive values are the same, your comparison evaluates to true. Hence, `false`

Here:

```
boolean result2 = (Boolean)first.get(m1) != (Boolean)second.get(m2);
```

You are comparing the references of the two objects. Since they are stored in different memory locations, the result of the comparison is `true`. *Intuitive, isn't it? Different object, different memory location?*.

If you really need to compare the values of two objects, use the `equals()` methods. In case of `Wrapper` objects however, close your eyes, unbox them to their primitive values and then compare.

**Just like Josh Bloch suggests in Effective Java: *Comparing Wrappers? Unbox the suckers!!***
*Just more from Effective Java, comparison operators work in case of `Wrapper` class if they have a greater than or less than sign attached to them. `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` yield the correct result even if you do not unbox. `==` and `!=` do not yield correct result*

Answer (score 1):

The comparation `boolean result1 = b1 != b2` is a primitive value comparation, so you can use operators like == or !=.

The comparation `boolean result2 = (Boolean)first.get(m1) != (Boolean)second.get(m2)` is an object comparation, so you are not comparing values, but references. You should compare them by using equals()

Like `boolean result2 = ((Boolean)first.get(m1)).equals((Boolean)second.get(m2))`